# Using Solargraph in VSCode, do I need to run the commands form the solargraph docs for each Ruby or Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

Commands such as `gem install solargraph` and `solargraph download-core`, `solargraph config`, etc.

Do I need to run these commands in each project directory, or is it like, run them once and solargraph is configured from now on in every project?

[Solargraph page](https://solargraph.org/guides/getting-started)

Comment: does `gem` install it local (workspace) or global (ruby install dir), does ruby have virtual environments like Python

Comment: Depending on your environment (rvm for example), there should be some possibility to install a gem globally (ie it will be accessible for all projects). What are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about the commands that you share here:

> gem install solargraph

You will need to run this command on each ruby version that your projects use, not in each project directory.

> solargraph download-core

This command install the best match for your Ruby version, but most of the time you'll be just fine with the first command. How should we use it? Just like the first one.

> solargraph config

The only command we need to run in all projects even if they have the same ruby ​​version, it will create a .solargraph.yml in our project, and with that we can add a custom configuration for the solargraph to that project. It's optional, sometimes the default setting is enough.

Reference: https://github.com/castwide/solargraph